# Matplotlib3D отображение временной оси

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Не получается сделать временную ось, вылазит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Professional/Desktop/History_spectrs/History_spectrs/bin/Debug/kascad.py", line 60, in <module>
    ax.plot(xlist, ylist, zlist,"-k",linewidth = 0.5)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1428, in plot
    self.auto_scale_xyz(xs, ys, zs, had_data)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 496, in auto_scale_xyz
    np.column_stack([X, Y]), not had_data)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 875, in update_from_data_xy
    path = Path(xy)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 127, in __init__
    vertices = _to_unmasked_float_array(vertices)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1317, in _to_unmasked_float_array
    return np.asarray(x, float)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

В принципе ошибка понятна, но как исправить не знаю. Гуглил, но ничего не помогло.

```
#выборка из бд
records = cursor.fetchall()
for row in records:
    zlist.append(row[0])
    ylist.append(row[1])
    #d =row[3]
    #date = DT.datetime.strptime(str(d),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    #xlist.append(pd.to_datetime(row[3]))
    xlist.append(row[3])

    if (row[1] == 2046): #конец одного графика
       
        ax.plot(xlist, ylist, zlist,"-k",linewidth = 0.5)
        temp.append(i)
        i += 2
        xlist.clear()
        ylist.clear()
        zlist.clear()
        label.append(str(row[3]))
        print(row[3])
    # make labels
cursor.close()
conn.close()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
#plt.xticks(temp,label,rotation=90)
#locator = matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator ()
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator (locator)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Пытаюсь построить график как на картинке:

[image: Пытаюсь построить график как на картинке.]

Comment: В код вставьте эти строку print('Тип {0}-{1}-{2}'.format(xlist, ylist, zlist)) и посмотрите что она распечатают если не float значит приведите к типу float должны все три значения быть типо такие 1.6

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
import numpy
import pandas
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib


now = datetime.datetime.now()
date_time_now = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

date_time = []

for _ in range(10):
    date_time.append(date_time_now)
    sleep(1)

dates_formatted = [pandas.to_datetime(_) for _ in date_time ]

print(date_time_now)

figure = plot.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


#axes.plot(x, y, z,"-k",linewidth = 0.5)
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
    xs = numpy.arange(200)
    ys = numpy.random.rand(200)

    cs = [c] * len(xs)

    cs[0] = 'c'
    axes.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

axes.xaxis.set_ticks(xs)
axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels(dates_formatted)


locator = matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator ()
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)


axes.set_xlabel('X')
axes.set_ylabel('Y')
axes.set_zlabel('Z')

plot.show()
```

Comment: ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (200), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (10).